# Kubernetes: Route incoming traffic to specific Pod

Tags: kubernetes, network-programming, kubernetes-ingress, google-kubernetes-engine, istio

I want to deploy many Pods in Google Kubernetes Engine and then establish a TCP connection to each specific Pod by Subdomain like pod-name-or-label.mydomain.com or path routing like protocol://mydomain.com:7878/pod-name-or-label.

I have looked in different directions like Istio or nginx-ingress, but that seems to me to be too complicated.

Is not there a simple solution for that?

Comment: A standalone `Pod` is not the way to go for this and is most certainly an anti-pattern. Your best bet is to move up a couple abstractions to the `Deployment` resource, and then you can deploy multiple copies of your `Pod` with some variation in labels between them to dictate ingress and routing.

Comment: Pod is not something to work with in production , define a deployment and expose it using nodePort , then use session persistence with kube-proxy set to serve from local node only.

Comment: This [article](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/exposing-apps#top_of_page) shows how to create Kubernetes Services in a Google Kubernetes Engine cluster And how to create a service of [Nodeport](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/exposing-apps#creating_a_service_of_type_nodeport).

Answer (score 2):

For **Istio**, You can use [VirtualService](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/traffic-management/#virtual-services) to control the **routing rules** to the target **subset** with defining by [DestinationRules](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/traffic-management/#destination-rules).

The **DestinationRule** will route to the target **Pods** by the **specified label** pods.

The request flow will like to:

```
+--------------------+
|                    |
|    Istio Gateway   |
|                    |
|                    |
+---------+----------+
          |traffic incoming
          |
+---------v----------+
|                    |
|   VirtualService   |
|                    |
|                    |
+---------+----------+
          |route to subset by the routing rules
          v

+--------------------+
|                    |
|  DestinationRules  |
|                    |
|                    |
+---------+----------+
          |route traffic to target pods
          v

+--------------------+
|                    |
|                    |
|       Pods         |
|                    |
+--------------------+
```

so as @ericstaples said you should create different **Deployments** with different **pod labels** to achieve separating **traffic** to **the target pods**, Example:

1. create a deployment with pod label: t1
2. create a subset in *DestinationRule*: select t1 label pod as subset s1
3. control your traffic in **VirtualService** that route to `s1` subset
4. `s1` route to the target pods

also for expose **Gateway**, you can use **ClusterIP** or **NodePort** like ** Kubernetes** other service did, see more of [Istio Traffic](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/#determining-the-ingress-ip-and-ports).

There are some references maybe it's helpful:

https://istio.io/docs/concepts/traffic-management/

https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/request-routing/

Answer (score 1):

This question is bit old, but in current Kubernetes versions you can do it easly using [Nginx Ingress](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/).

If you want to reach your application from outside the cluster you need to expose it using [Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#defining-a-service). Easiest way is to use Service with selectors when you put the same [selector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/#label-selectors) in `Deployment/Pod` and `Service`. Example below:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      key: test1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        key: test1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello1
        image: gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:1.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test1
spec:
  selector:
    key: test1
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
```

Path routing will be configured in [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/). As on the example below:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: my.pod.svc 
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /pod
        backend:
          serviceName: my-pod
          servicePort: 80
  - host: nginx.test.svc
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /abc
        backend:
          serviceName: nginx1
          servicePort: 80
```

For more details you can check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55106849/find-why-i-am-getting-502-bad-gateway-error-on-kubernetes/56148802).

Answer (score 0):

Now i have that solution with istio installed on the cluster:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: echo-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default controller
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "dev.sample.com"
```

With that gateway i can apply that Deployment, Service, VirtualService

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-echo-1000-deployment
  labels:
    echoservice: echo-1000
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      echoservice: echo-1000
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        echoservice: echo-1000
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: gcr.io/google-containers/echoserver:1.10
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: my-echo-run-container
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-echo-1000-service
  labels:
    echoservice: echo-1000
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    name: http
  selector:
    echoservice: echo-1000

---

apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: my-echo-1000-vservice
spec:
  hosts:
  - "dev.sample.com"
  gateways:
  - echo-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        exact: /echo-1000
    route:
    - destination:
        host: my-echo-1000-service
        port:
          number: 8080
```

Get the LoadbalancerIP from  istio-ingressgateway and make an entry in /etc/hosts for dev.sample.com

Now i can get the echoserver in specific Pod with http://dev.sample.com/echo-1000

Is that a good solution or is there a better one?